# Is this code snippet that guards against 'undefined' out of date or a mistake?

Tags: javascript

In this book, JavaScript Definitive Guide - 6th Edition, page 123, there is a code snippet:

```
//A concise and idiomatic alternative to get subtitle length or undefined
var len = book && ("subtitle" in book) && book.subtitle.length;
```

It is supposed to prevent TypeError exceptions, but this code snippet will generate `an Uncaught Reference Error: book is not defined` instead.

I think a better way to provide a more comprehensive coverage is:

```
var len = typeof book !== "undefined" && ("subtitle" in book) && book.subtitle.length;
```

So that we can guard against the scenario that variable book being undefined as well.

I am wondering if this example above is a mistake.

Comment: I think the example assumes that `book` is a *declared* variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't like checking if things exist in the logic. Instead you can set some defaults beforehand to make life easier. For example you could use:

```
// assuming book is a declared variable

// set defaults
if (!book) book = {};
if (!book.subtitle) book.subtitle = "";

// do stuff without worrying if book is missing or has no subtitle
var len = book.subtitle.length;
```

Alternatively you could also use variable destruction, although this may look more cryptic.

```
// assuming book is a declared variable

var {subtitle: {length} = ""} = book || {};
//                      ^^^^         ^^^^^- default book to an empty object (if book is falsy)
//                      | default subtitle to an empty string (if property is undefined)
```

You could also make use of the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) here. Note that this feature is fairly new and not yet implemented in all browsers. If in any point the value of `book` or `subtitle` is `undefined` or `null`, the optional chaining operator will return `undefined`.

```
var length = book?.subtitle?.length || 0;
//   use 0 if book or the subtitle  ^^^^
//   property are undefined or null
```

Comment: if we assume book is declared, why do we still check if(!book)? there are two possible scenarios, 1: book is declared, then we will never reach book = {}; 2: book is not declared, and we will get an error from if(!book).

Comment: I see it now, declared !== assigned. a declared variable can still be undefined.

Comment: @YuZhang Indeed. Declared only means that the program knows that there is a variable named `book`. Assigned means that you have assigned a value to the variable `book`. I've also updated the answer with an "optional chaining operator" solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd example you are missing `typeof`. It should be rare these days that variables aren't declared.

Comment: spot on, thanks, I indeed missed out typeof, added now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong about your assumptions. you are attempting to get rid of a valid error. the second piece of code you wrote in fact does not throw an error, but you would want it to if you never defined that variable anywhere in your code. that is a valid error that you want to get, in my opinion.

I would use the first version in your code. or even write:

```
var book;    
var len = book && book.subtitle && book.subtitle.length;
// len = undefined
```